# Errors encountered during job execution. Unexpected. Please try again.

Tags: google-bigquery

In the last few days, I am trying to upload files to my BigQuery table but it keeps failing with: "Errors encountered during job execution. Unexpected. Please try again."
JobsIds for example: 
job_8bf7e7d257884d3bab2e04ac1208fedb
job_4354aa20427a4453ab14f9f18365d216
job_8b287b73b19d4a8a9dacc5f002e265a9

I have checked that there are no lines greater than 64K.
Please help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the data syntax. I have divided the file into 4 pieces and they all completed the uploading job.  
The original gzipped file size was 328M and it failed.
Even a half size (177M) of the gzipped file was failed.
Each of the divided parts (>90M) completed the job.
Maybe you changed your gzipped limitation from 1GB to 100MB?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've encountered an internal error within BigQuery's upload code.  We'll investigate further, but in the meantime, one potential workaround is to upload your data to Google Cloud Storage temporarily and then import to BigQuery from there.  (You can delete the Cloud Storage object as soon as the BigQuery import is complete.)

Sorry about the trouble!

Comment: Did you found the problem?